# Javascript array map to propery (item => item[prop])?

Tags: javascript

Im learning javascript and looking over some code and ran into this:

`array.map(item => item[prop])` where prop may be something like `'id'` or something.

I haven't been able to find an actual example of this on the web. So I tried just doing something like this:

```
property = 'id';
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
var something = arr.map(item => item[property]);
console.log(something);
```

This doesn't work however. And I can't seem to find an example on the web. Is this a new type of syntax for the map function?

Comment: ES6 Arrow function. Here's an example using `map`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Shorter_functions

Comment: Why are you trying to get the `id` property of a number? You say it "doesn't work", but it's returning an array of `undefined`, which is the expected output.

Comment: I guess I assume undefined should not be correct? I know the data in the program this is written in that's passed through this function is in fact an array of numbers

Comment: If that program uses an Array of numbers, and they ask for the `id` property of each number, then unless `Number.prototype` has been given an `id` property, they will get an Array of `undefined` as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "arrow function" is a shorthand way of writing functions.

```
item => item[property]
```

It is (mostly) equivalent to writing:

```
function(item){
    return item[property];
}
```

Your `arr` array contains numbers, so in the function `item` will be a *number*.  Numbers do not have an `'id'` property, so that's why it "doesn't work".

Consider if you had something like:

```
var prop = 'id';
var arr = [{id:1, name:"one"}, {id:2, name:"two"}];
var something = arr.map(item => item[prop]);
console.log(something);
```

`something` would end up being `[1, 2]`.

Comment: What if I made the numbers strings? Would that work? I know in the program (I made a console.log statement on the "data") and it was indeed an array of numbers. But maybe those numbers were actually objects...

Comment: What do you mean by "work"?  What output are you expecting?  Neither strings nor numbers have an `id` property.  In case you don't know, doing `a['id']` is the same as doing `a.id`.

Comment: Nevermind I realized what I did wrong, the original "array" was actually an array of objects and not numbers. No wonder it didn't work)